# Forms containing random description

Tags: wolfram-cloud

I would like to create a form with `FormFunction[]` that contains random elements in description. As an example I would like to create a form that generates two random numbers, a and b, and asks a user to choose the larger number.

Creating a form with description is relatively simple, say I have the following code.

```
FormFunction[
 {
  "<h1 style=\"color:black; font-family:verdana\">Play a little \
game</h1>",
  "<p style=\"color:black; font-family:verdana\">There are two \
numbers a = " <> ToString[RandomReal[]] <> " and b = " <> 
   ToString[RandomReal[]] <> ". Which one is larger?",
  "x" -> <|"Interpreter" -> {"A" -> 1, "B" -> 2},
    "Control" -> (RadioButtonBar[##, Appearance -> "Vertical"] &),
    "Label" -> "Select number",
    "Help" -> "Select the larger number"|>,
  },
 Identity,
 PageTheme -> "Blue"
 ]
```

The above code results in the following static form.

[image]

The form is, however, static, that is it does not change when reloaded.

**Question**

How can I make it dynamic, that is, every time the page is reloaded the numbers are generated anew. I have experimented with `Delayed[]` but to no avail. (Edit). I would also like to know the randomly generated numbers in the submit function.

**Alternative answer**

One answer is provided below. In the mean time, based on the same idea, I came up with a slightly different code. The solution below creates an API function that is deployed to a directory `testDir`. Every time the function is called it produces a different form (random), deploys to a subdirectory `RandomForms` under a different name and redirects to it. Such solution produces a new form every time a function is called. This can be solved either by manually cleaning the subdirectory `RandomForms` or by adding such statement in the submit function of a random form.

```
CloudDeploy[
 APIFunction[
  {},
  Function[
   a = RandomReal[];
   b = RandomReal[];
   dir = CreateUUID[];
   HTTPRedirect@CloudDeploy[FormFunction[
      {
       Style["Little form", "Title"],
       Style["First number: " <> ToString[a], "Text"],
       Style["Second number: " <> ToString[b], "Text"],
       "x" -> <|"Label" -> "Selection", 
         "Interpreter" -> {"A" -> 1, "B" -> 2}, 
         "Control" -> RadioButtonBar|>
       },
      ({a, b, #x} &)
      ], FileNameJoin[{$CloudRootDirectory, "testDir", "RandomForms", 
       dir}]]
   ]
  ],
 FileNameJoin[{$CloudRootDirectory, "testDir", "fun1"}],
 Permissions -> "Private"
 ]
```

For public use the obvious changes need to be introduced.

Comment: Always try to reduce an example to a minimum. Here the theme and html styling is not relevant at all.

Comment: FWIW, I think this is a very well-written question...

Comment: Also, don't you want to know those numbers in the submit function? Because this may be trickier.

Comment: @Kuba This is an excellent point, yes, I would like to know these numbers in the submit function. Also, I agree that the styling is not necessary but here it provides a context of the question: what I'm trying to do is to generate a simple task to check if the user understands the question. In fact, this is already very simpilified since if it is possible I will use it to generate a random example of a simple two-player normal-form game and ask for a payoff associated with randomly generated strategies.

Comment: I thought this should work: `With[{a = RandomReal[], b = RandomReal[]},
   FormFunction[{
     StringTemplate["A = `` and B = ``. Which one is bigger?"][a, b], 
     "x" -> {"A" -> 1, "B" -> 2}},
    {#x, a, b, a > b, #x === If[a > b, 1, 2]} &
    ]
   ] // Delayed // CloudDeploy[#, Permissions -> "Public"] &` but numbers are reset on submit too... I'm not even surprised anymore. Alternatively you could create APIFunction which deploys a from and redirects automatically.

Comment: Are you looking at this things in the front end? Or did you try to `CloudDeploy[Delayed[.......]]` ? Also you have a typo - is it extra coma hanging after `"Select the larger number"|>,` ? It works perfectly for me in the cloud with both `FormFunction ` and `FormPage `

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov I guess OP didn't wrap Delayed around FormFunction. I must say that wasn't the obvious choice for me to and I started with `Delayed` content. Anyway, have you tried my example? Can you reproduce the double evaluation too? If so, then I'd argue with 'works perfectly'.

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov Yes, I deploy to cloud otherwise things like `PageTheme` do not work.

Comment: @Kuba Your solution works perfectly. I will post an answer based on your solution. As a side note I have to say that the documentation distributed with Mathematica and available on Wolfram pages is severely lacking. I really appreciate your help. Can you point me to any tutorial on how to write an APIFunction that creates a page with a form and on submit redirects to another APIFunction that creates another page like this so I can chain forms but a form need to take an argument (I need to identify a person so I need to pass a user id along).

Comment: @Michal but if I click submit the response contains different values of a and b, does not it?

Comment: @Kuba Ahh, yes. I've just checked that. But it seems like the results is correct. I will investigate.

Comment: @Kuba Well, no. The result may be wrong so it seems like the `If[]` statement uses reset values of `a` and `b`. It seems that `FunctionForm[]` is only good for very static collection of data. I need to investigate `APIFunction[]` and see what this is capable of. Anyway, thanks for your help, I've learnt a lot.

Comment: @Michal as I mentioned to Kuba the solution works for me without that inner `CloudDeploy.

Comment: I'll test that. It would be better if it worked, that would mean that the form is never deployed to cloud and no cleaning is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know why `Delayed` fires again on 'submit' event so here is an example with an APIFunction that will generated and redirect to a FormFunction each time it is called:

```
 formTemplate = TemplateExpression @ TemplateWith[{"a" -> RandomReal[], "b" -> RandomReal[]
    },
   FormFunction[{"Play a little game", 
     StringTemplate@
      "There are two numbers a = `a` and b = `b`. Which one is \
larger?", 
     "x" -> <|"Interpreter" -> {"A" -> 1, "B" -> 2}, 
       "Control" -> RadioButtonBar|>}, #x == 
      If[TemplateSlot["a"] > TemplateSlot["b"], 1, 2] &, 
    PageTheme -> "Blue"]];


With[{formTemplate = formTemplate},
  APIFunction[{}, HTTPRedirect@CloudDeploy[
      TemplateApply@formTemplate
      , Permissions -> "Public"] &
   ]
] // CloudDeploy[#, Permissions -> "Public"] &
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Am I wrong or does this solution deploy an unnamed cloud object every time it is called and redirects to it? If so, aren't we going to end up with a lot of random unnamed objects? On the other hand, this has the advantage that I can pass arguments like user id.

Comment: @Michal yep, unfortunately t does this. You can use `CloudDeploy[(*form*), CreateUUID["randomForms/"], ...]` and clean this directory from time to time.

Comment: OK, taking into account expected number of uses this will not be a problem. I can also use `DeleteFile[CloudObjects[None]]` to remove all unnamed objects (I always use named objects) or maybe set up a scheduled task. That's fine I will accept the answer.

Comment: One more thing.  If an initial value of an input is defined as `RuleDelayed[]` the value is also lost in the submit function (is generated anew). Otherwise I could use disabled `Input[]` to catch the value. Now it needs to be enabled so even if I do not show it on a page a user can still focus on a field and delete the value or change it.

Comment: I've just tested the answer. If used the way it is it produces a random form and redirect to it. However, the function is fixed, so when called next time it gives the same form with the same numbers. Those numbers are visible to the submit function in the form. If in the template code `"a"->RandomReal[]` is changed to `"a":>RandomReal[]` then the function generates random  form every time it is called but the number are not available to the submit function in the form.

Comment: @Michal fixed, by alternative solution with `TemplateExpression`. Thanks for paying attention.

Comment: Nice. In the mean time I came up with a different solution (the idea is the same just a different code). I added the answer to the original question. Thanks again, I learned a lot.

Comment: @Kuba I don't think you need that inner `CloudDeploy`. Works for me without it.